# Array filter - get rid of O(n^2)

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I need to perform 2 filters on array of objects which is very big (over 200k elements) so I want my code to be as fast as possible in javascript.

First filter is simple because I just need to delete elements which are empty (null):

```
let validArr = originalArr.filter(el => { return el != null });
```

Second filter is to check if `validArr[i].name` is equal to one of elements from other array. Currently I do it like this:

```
for(let i = 0, l = validArr.length; i < l; i++) {
    if (findInArray(validArr[i].name, otherArr)) {
        finalArr.push({
            name: validNpc[i].nick,
            id: validNpc[i].id
        });
    }
}

const findInArray = (val, arr) => {
    for(let i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {
        if(arr[i] === val) return true;
    }
    return false;
};
```

In loop I have micro optimization but there is O(n^2) which I want to refactor but I don't know how.

Comment: some example data will be helpful please add it.

Comment: What exactly are those values in `validArr` "name" properties? If they're strings, you can turn `otherArr` into a simple object with the "name" values as property names and something like `true` or `1` as the values. Then you can just do one simple property lookup.

Comment: @Pointy Or use a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).

Comment: @melpomene yes of course; I don't do that much because in my personal world I'm stuck with ES5 mostly but it'd be much better.

Comment: otherArr is array of strings

Comment: Minor note, `.filter(el => { return el != null })` can be condensed to `.filter(el => !!el)`.

Comment: The code added does not work, `.slice` does not mutate anything, also I'm not clear what ut is supposed to do. Nevertheless I think you can easily adapt the answers provided to it. I'm going to roll back your edit as it totally changes the question (edit is for editing, not for adding a new question)

Comment: Ok I'll accept your answer then and try to adapt it my third filtering.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turn otherArr into a Set, then lookup takes O(1) and the overall loop is O(n):

```
  const names = new Set(otherArr);

  const result = validArr
    .filter(it => names.has(it.name))
    .map(({ nick, id }) => ({ name: nick, id }));
```

Comment: Thank you actually now when I think of it I will also need third filter, I'm sorry I didn't mention it in question, give me a minute and I will edit my question.

Comment: And what about the constructor (`new Set(otherArr)`), is it linear? I couldn't find the info.

Comment: @mbojko yup, it has to be.

Comment: I checked on jsperf set vs loop and it shows like loop is faster... But only on array with lower amount of elements than 200. https://jsperf.com/loop-vs-set/1 Is your example linear for sure? How `.has` method know it contain value in collection without looping on it?

Comment: @bt101 yes, time complexity only gives a good measure for larger datasets. As you said, it will be better for 200 elements or more. Creation / Insertion / Lookup on a Map is O(1), but those operations are still costly. You only get its benefit if n grows. And you should read about [Hashtables](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Set` and `has` method which have O(1) time complexity

```
otherArr = new Set(otherArr);
for(let i = 0, l = validArr.length; i < l; i++) {
    if (findInArray(validArr[i].name, otherArr)) {
        finalArr.push({
            name: validNpc[i].nick,
            id: validNpc[i].id
        });
    }
}

const findInArray = (val, arr) => {
    return arr.has(val)
};
```

You can clean up your code using `forEach()`

```
otherArr = new Set(otherArr)
const finalArr = [];
validArr.forEach(x => {
    if(otherArr.has(x.name)){
       finalArr.push({ name:x.nick, id:x.id })
    }
})
```

Comment: You're not really using `reduce` to build up a value. You're just using it for its side effect of iterating over an array. The same code could be written using `filter` or `map` or `forEach`.

Comment: @melpomene I got it what you mean. I updated with `forEach` solution.